# Sous Vide temperature accuracy

Tags: temperature

I'm starting a Sous Vide project and I didn't find any information about Temperature Accuracy. I really would like to know how accurate must be the temperature sensor in Sous Vide.
 I found some DIY Sous Vide that uses DS18B20 with 0.5ºC accuracy, will it be enough or Sous Vide must require better accuracy such as we can find on commercial products.

Comment: Welcome to the site @AntonioBorges. Who says commercial products are more accurate?

Answer (score 2):

Most home kitchen immersion circulators advertise that they are accurate in the .1 to .3 degree F range.  Practically speaking, if you were considering a home-made device, you can easily get away with less accuracy than that.  So, .5 would be just fine.  In a pinch, I've used a pot of water and a thermometer, turning the gas on an off.  Not very convenient, not very accurate, but it can work with close monitoring.  By the way, I do sometime set my circulator to .5 degree increments, but, honestly, that's probably more obsessiveness than is required.